# SELECT rows based on values in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Here's my table

```
 ID  prod   Num 
-------------------
| 1 | A  |  4
| 1 | B  |  3
| 1 | K  |  2
| 2 | A  |  4
| 2 | B  |  4
| 2 | C  |  2
| 3 | A  |  1
| 3 | K  |  4
```

First I need all rows where Num = 4 and there exists Prod = K for this same ID

Result 1 should be

```
ID  prod   num 
-------------------
| 1 | A  |  4
| 1 | B  |  3
| 1 | K  |  2
| 3 | A  |  1
| 3 | K  |  4
```

I also need another result where there are only rows: Num=4 or Prod=K 
 from first query

Result 2:

```
ID  prod   num 
-------------------
| 1 | A  |  4
| 1 | K  |  2
| 3 | A  |  1
| 3 | K  |  4
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Result 2 seems to be inconsistent with the search criteria given, specifically record `(3,  'A',  1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Result 1:

```
select t.id,t.prod,t.num
from mytable t 
join
(select distinct id
from mytable x
where num = 4
and exists(select 1 from mytable where id = x.id and prod = 'K') ) x
on t.id = x.id
```

Result 2:

```
with res1 as (select t.id,t.prod,t.num
from mytable t 
join
(select distinct id
from mytable x
where num = 4
and exists(select 1 from mytable where id = x.id and prod = 'K') ) x
on t.id = x.id
)
select * from res1 where num = 4 or prod = 'K'
```

You can try this.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edb01/9)

Comment: Edited my answer as i misunderstood the question previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
WHERE Num = 4 OR Prod = 'K'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Prod = 'K' THEN 1 END) <> 0 
       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Num = 4 THEN 1 END) <> 0
```

to get the `ID` values that meet your search requirements, i.e. `(1), (3)`.

Applying the `IN` operator on the above gives you the required result set 1:

```
SELECT ID, prod, Num
FROM mytable
WHERE ID IN (
   SELECT ID
   FROM mytable
   WHERE Num = 4 OR Prod = 'K'
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Prod = 'K' THEN 1 END) <> 0 
          AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Num = 4 THEN 1 END) <> 0 )
```

To get result set 2 just add `Num=4 OR Prod='K'` predicate to the `WHERE` clause of the above query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/126bc/2)

Answer (score 0):

For the first query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 ON t2.id = t.id AND t2.num=4
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t3 ON t3.id =t.id AND t3.prod='K'
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL AND t3.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.id,t.prod
```

And the second query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 ON t2.id = t.id AND t2.num=4
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t3 ON t3.id =t.id AND t3.prod='K'
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL AND t3.id IS NOT NULL
AND (t.num=4 OR t.prod='K')
ORDER BY t.id,t.prod
```